# I need to make a number input by user to output individual digits using C++

Tags: c++

I need to make a number that was input by a user into individual digits using only while and for loops.

I used while loops to count the number of digits in the number but for my for-loop I cannot seem to get it processed. What am I doing wrong?

I do know I need to do `10^` number of digits, but I don't know how to do that since `^` does not exist in C++.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int n;
cout<< "please enter an integer: ";
cin>>n;
int a=n;
int count=0;
while(a>0){
a/=10;
count++;
}
int num= 10*(count-1);
for (int n=0;num<0;n++){
   cout<<n/num<<endl;
   n%=num;
   num/=10;
   }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: also please change the variable `n` in for loop to `i`

Comment: We don't know what you can or cannot use since most (if not all) of the people helping you did not attend your class.  Nevertheless, the simplest way to get powers of 10 is not to compute them at runtime.  Store the answer in an array and index the array: `long pow10 [ ] = {1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 10000000, 100000000};`  then to simply get `10^2` would be `pow10[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

The code fails for numbers which have greater than 2 digits, because value of `num` must `10^(count-1)` not `10*(count-1)`

There is a function `pow(base,exp)` in C++ which can be used in this case as `num=pow(10,count-1)`

or you could try creating num variable while counting the number of digits:

```
int count=0,num=1;
while(a>0){
    a/=10;
    count++;
    num*=10;
}
num = num/10;
for (int i=0;i<count;i++){
    cout<<n/num<<endl;
    n%=num;
    num/=10;
}
```

return 0;
Adding last line just to remove an extra 10, since `num=10^(count-1)`

Comment: The only problem is that I have not learned the pow function therefore I cannot use it. Is there any other way i can do it without the pow function?

Comment: I tried the advice you have given me but there is not output besides "please enter an integer:"

Comment: You are using variable 'n' in for loop too .. Please change it to 'i"

Comment: I was able to answer it with two while loops. Thank you for your help :)